# How to use MongoDB findOne() with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm having troubles using the MongoDB findOne() function together with mongoose.

**controller**

```
exports.show = function (req, res) {
   Fahrt.load(req.params.fahrtenId, function (err, fahrt) {
       res.jsonp(fahrt);
   });
};
```

**model**

```
FahrtSchema.statics = {
load: function (id, cb) {
    this.findOne({
            _id: id
        }
    ).exec(cb);
}};
```

**route**

```
router.get('/:fahrtId', fahrtenController.show);
```

**app.js**

```
app.use('/fahrten', fahrten);
```

When I use Postman to query for a "Fahrt"Object with a specific ID I get back "null". When I search with the Mongo Console directly via

```
db.Fahrt.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("5562ca06a14c4924090ba5ff")})
```

I get an existing object and everything is as expected. But why not when I query via Mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter in your route is `:fahrtId`:

```
router.get('/:fahrtId', fahrtenController.show);
```

But you are trying to retrieve the value from `fahrtenId`:

```
req.params.fahrtenId
```